# Unable to start/stop/restart services inside the docker container

Tags: docker, containers, centos7

I understand that the containers, unlike VMs, don't have their own Kernel. To operate with services I had to do a systemd integration with the containers.

My main focus is to apply NAT rules in a container and then restart the network for them to take effect.

Followed the steps in - https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/centos#systemd-integration

shrey67/gateway-systemd is the same as local/c7-systemd

Starting the docker container with necessary privileges.

```
    docker run -it -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro --cpus="0.33" -
    -network=d1 --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --cap-add=NET_RAW --hostname Temp 
    --name Temp shrey67/gateway-systemd
```

Applying some NAT rules

```
    [root@Temp /]# iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -m state --
    state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    [root@Temp /]# iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth2 -j ACCEPT
    [root@Temp /]# iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth1 -m state --
    state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    [root@Temp /]# iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth2 -j ACCEPT
    [root@Temp /]# iptables -S
    -P INPUT ACCEPT
    -P FORWARD ACCEPT
    -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j 
    ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth2 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j 
    ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth2 -j ACCEPT

    [root@Temp /]# service iptables start
    Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start iptables.service
    Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

I am able to save the NAT rules.

```
   [root@Temp /]# service iptables save
   iptables: Saving firewall rules to /etc/sysconfig/iptables:[ OK ]

   [root@emp /]# service iptables restart
   Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart iptables.service
   Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted

   [root@Temp /]# systemctl restart iptables.service
   Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

The host machine is CentOS 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this issue resolved. I am able to start/stop/restart services after following these two steps.

Step 1 - Integrate systemd with container. Follow this link.

```
    https://github.com/docker-
    library/docs/tree/master/centos#systemd-integration
```

Step 2 - Start container with the privileged flag.

```
    docker run -it -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro --privileged 
    ubuntu
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the records, you could have avoided the venerable "Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted" by using the https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement ;) ... but I am not sure whether that would be good enough to start an iptables. That's because iptables are in the kernel AFAIK, so there's hardly any point fiddling with it inside a container.